# workflow lists sharepoint office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, office-365

I have a request list with a field called `Lead` (person). When someone fills in a request, an email is sent to the chief using a Flow (when a new item is added). The chief has to go to the URL given in the email.

At the list, the chief fills in a person from a SharePoint group I created. Once he has done this, I want SharePoint to send an approval mail to the Lead.

I made a Flow: when an existing list item is modified, complete a custom action. In this flow I have set the following condition:

`@contains(triggerBody()?['Lead']?['Email'], 'minfin')`

`minfin` is something that comes always in the email address. I would rather like to use something like empty, but couldn't get the right expression.

`@(empty(triggerBody()?['Lead']?['Email'],'')`

If this condition is true, 1 setting (`Chiefapproval`) is updated with OK and an approval email is sent to the `Leadperson`.

Afterward I do a new request, the `Leadperson` receives more than 38 approval emails for every request that has been done....

I don't use designer (it is not allowed).

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179762/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-workflow-by-updating-only-a-value-in-a-list-item-ap

So, I made an extra column called `Lead control`. Now I can control if the `lead control` is the same as the `Lead`, then don't do anything, otherwise, update the column `Lead control`. But I can't update a column that has as type persons (from a sharepoint group.)
Anyone?

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem. I had a field 'Approval' where I put a value OK or NOK. I made another field 'Control Approval' and checked If they where equal. If they where Equal nothing happened. If they where not Equal, I put the value from 'Approval' into the field 'Control Approval' and it did work.